# Запятые в предложении с союзом Как.., так и

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно расставить запятые в предложении.

Настоящее учебно-методическое пособие предназначено для студентов как очной, так и заочной форм обучения(?) и направлено на освоение не только теоретических основ, но, что наиболее существенно, и практической стороны изучаемой дисциплины.

Answer (score 1):

Настоящее учебно-методическое пособие предназначено для студентов **как очной, так и заочной форм обучения**  и направлено на освоение не только теоретических основ, но, что наиболее существенно, и практической стороны изучаемой дисциплины.

Однородные  определения "как очной, так и заочной"   связаны **двойным сопоставительным союзом КАК...ТАК И, между ними ставится запятая, но они не обособляются**, сравнить:

Настоящее учебно-методическое пособие предназначено для студентов  **очной  и заочной форм обучения**  и направлено на освоение не только теоретических основ, но, что наиболее существенно, и практической стороны изучаемой дисциплины (союз И связывает однородные сказуемые).